# Python: printing strings from another file

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, file, readfile

I want to call a file, erase its data, write new lines and print it. 
Below is my program and its output.

```
from sys import argv
string, filename = argv
text = open(filename, 'w+')
text.truncate()
line1 = "hey"
line2 = "I was doing just fine before I met you"
line3 = "I drink too much and that's an issue but I'm okay"
text.write('%s\n%s\n%s\n' %(line1, line2, line3))
new = text.read()
old = text.readlines()
print "%s" %(new)
print old
print text.readlines()
text.close()
```

Output:

[]
[]

Comment: `text = open(filename, 'w')`. That's it, you're set. Anyway, if you want to read from it again, you'll have to open it once more in `'r'` mode.

Comment: @Shiva Then it is giving error for text.read(), not opened in read mode.

Comment: @Mihir You need to open the file in read mode before you can read it.

Comment: @ILostMySpoon I opened my file with 'w' and again open it with 'r' for reading, it worked! But why 'w+' is not working for both reading and writing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So adding seek(0) will do the job here.
seek(0) set the pointer at the beginning. 
Here's the working code:

```
    from sys import argv
    string, filename = argv


    text = open(filename, 'w+')
    text.truncate()

    line1 = "hey"
    line2 = "I was doing just fine before I met you"
    line3 = "I drink too much and that's an issue but I'm okay"

    text.write('%s\n%s\n%s\n' %(line1, line2, line3))
    text.seek(0)
    new = text.read()
    text.seek(0)
    old = text.readlines()
    print "%s" %(new)
    print old
    text.seek(0)
    print text.readlines()

    text.close()
```

Output:

hey
I was doing just fine before I met you
I drink too much and that's an issue but I'm okay

['hey\n', 'I was doing just fine before I met you\n', "I drink too much and that's an issue but I'm okay\n"]
['hey\n', 'I was doing just fine before I met you\n', "I drink too much and that's an issue but I'm okay\n"]

Answer (score 1):

So, your error (by your comments is that it isn't letting you read).

This is because your trying to read using a file pointer which was used to open the file in write mode.

```
from sys import argv
string, filename = argv
with open(filename, 'w') as text:
    line1 = "hey"
    line2 = "I was doing just fine before I met you"
    line3 = "I drink too much and that's an issue but I'm okay"
    text.write('%s\n%s\n%s\n' %(line1, line2, line3))

with open(filename, 'r') as text:
    ...
```

Comment: Might as well use `w+` seeing as the OP wants to erase the file's data before writing the new lines to it. This way he doesn't need to call `truncate` either.

Comment: I am also using truncate. So for reading + writing + truncate , we use 'w+' then why can't I use it here ?

Comment: @Mihir There is really no reason to call `truncate` if you are opening the file with `w+` other than showing that you can...

Comment: @ILostMySpoon Done finally! Used text.seek(0) to set the pointer at the beginning and it worked.